# When should I unsubscribe from firestore listener?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing a social app where users can check if they have new messages when they navigate to `ChatList` page. My idea is the following. On `useEffect` I load the newest 10 chats. Then if the user wants to see their oldest chats, I will have "more" button which will load nxt batch of chats. I don't want to load everything at once, since some users may have lost of chats. This is part of my code:

```
import { fetchInitialChats, fetchNextChats } from "./actions";

function ChatList(props) {
  const limit = 10;
  const [chats, setChats] = useState([]);
  const [lastFetched, setLastFetched] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("fetch initial chats");
    async function initialFetch() {
      let result;
      try {
        result = await fetchInitialChats(setLastFetched, limit);
        console.log("result: ", result);
        setChats(result);
        setError(false);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(true);
        console.log("Error during initial fetch of chats: ", error);
      }
    }
    initialFetch();
  }, []);
```

In my `actions.js` file I implement `fetchInitialChats` and  `fetchNextChats`:

```
export const fetchInitialChats = async (setLastFetched, limit) => {
  console.log("fetching initial batch of chats");
  let chats = [];
  let query = await firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("Chats")
    .where("users", "array-contains", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .orderBy("lastMessageTimestamp", "desc")
    .limit(limit);
  const unsubRef = query.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    chats = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
      const data = doc.data();
      const id = doc.id;
      return { id, ...data };
    });
   if (snapshot.docs.length > 0) {
     const last = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1];
     setLastFetched(last);
   }
  });
  unsubRef();
  return chats;
};
```

My questions are two:

1. Is this the right way to subscribe from a listener? Do I need to unsubscribe from `useEffect` or from somewhere else?
2. Is this actually the right way to perform pagination when using lister. If I am fetching chats with simple `get()`, without listening for new updates, sure, this is the way to go. What if I am listening to live updates and I want to perform pagination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your questions,

1. No, This is not the right way to add the listener to firestore or any other SDK, We should have to use the useEffect hook or custom hook to manage the listeners.
2. If you are about to implement the pagination, you can use the code below for you.

I have created a custom hook to manage the chat listener separately from the main screen code base.

**Note: This is sample code not a full feature working code make changes as per the requirements**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { FlatList } from 'react-native'

const useChats = (limit = 10) => {

    const [chatsData, setChatsData] = useState([])
    const [lastFetched, setLastFetched] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        let chats = [];
        let query = await firebase
                        .firestore()
                        .collection("Chats")
                        .where("users", "array-contains", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
                        .orderBy("lastMessageTimestamp", "desc")
                        .limit(limit);

        const unsubRef = query.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            chats = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
                const data = doc.data();
                const id = doc.id;
                return { id, ...data };
            });

            setChatsData(chats)

            if (snapshot.docs.length > 0) {
                const last = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1];
                setLastFetched(last);
            }
        });
        
        return unsubRef();
    }, [])

    const fetchMore = (limit = 10) => {
        let chats = [];
        let query = await firebase
                        .firestore()
                        .collection("Chats")
                        .where("users", "array-contains", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
                        .orderBy("lastMessageTimestamp", "desc")
                        .limit(limit)
                        .after(lastFetched)

        const unsubRef = query.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            chats = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
                const data = doc.data();
                const id = doc.id;
                return { id, ...data };
            });

            setChatsData(chats)

            if (snapshot.docs.length > 0) {
                const last = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1];
                setLastFetched(last);
            }
        });
        
        return unsubRef();
    }

    return [chatsData, lastFetched, { fetchMore }]
}

function ChatList(props) {
    const [chatsData, lastFetched, { fetchMore }] = useChats()

    return (
        <FlatList
            data={chatsData}
            renderItem={() => {
                return (
                    // Your chat rendering goes to here..
                )
            }}
            onEndReached={fetchMore}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0.01}
        />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetching items once don't require listening to new updates.

```js
export const fetchInitialChats = async (setLastFetched, limit) => {
  console.log("fetching initial batch of chats");

  let chatsRef = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("Chats")
    .where("users", "array-contains", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .orderBy("lastMessageTimestamp", "desc")
    .limit(limit);

  const snapshots = await chatsRef.get();

  // Utility function to extract docs from collection snapshots
  const extractSnapshots = (snapshots) => {
    let extracts = [];
    snapshots.forEach((documentSnapshot) => {
      extracts.push(documentSnapshot.data());
    });
    return extracts;
  };

  const chats = extractSnapshots(snapshots);


console.log({chats})

  if (chats.length > 0) {
    const last = chats[chats.length - 1];
    setLastFetched(last);
  }

  return chats;
};
```

then fetch initial chats when component mounted

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // fetchInitialChats(20)
}, []);
```